# What does a JSON-encoded request look like?

Tags: php, json, request

I'm building an API using PHP.

What do I need to do to recognize a JSON encoded request?

Does it come with a certain request type?

How do I get just the request body so that I can json_decode it?

Comment: What doyou mean by "get just the request body"? Are you acting as the server or the client? If you mean the response body, that depends on how you requested it, it you are acting as the server and receiving requests, it depends on your HTTP server and how it got the script. AKA is it GET or POST?

Comment: I am acting as the server. via POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) recommends the mime type application/json.  You can read the request data with [php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Answer (score 0):

The mime type for json is `application/json`, but I doubt that has caught on yet to add that to responses.

The easiest way to spot a json response is that it will most likely be wrapped in curly braces and have colons after each member. But that still isn't a sure fire way to know it's json.

The easiest way to test it from PHP is to try to json_decode it, if it throws an error, either it's not json, or it's not well-formed json and thus you won't be able to use it anyway.

Comment: i know what json looks like. the question is json_decode what? how do i get the 'json-encoded payload' to run json_decode on?

Comment: Ah, so I left you a comment in the main question. Are they passing it as POST? or are you actually retrieving it?

Comment: So if it's POST, it would depend on if it had a variable name. I would try both of the following: `print_r($_POST)`, to see if POST is still an array, and if so, what the json is keyed to, and I would try:  `json_decode($_POST)`. If I had to guess, it's a little of both:  `json_decode($_POST[0])`